# Query to return rooms that are free in a date-range in a hotel schema in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I need a bit of help in writing an SQL query.
A simple scenario is that I have a table named `BookedRooms` in which three columns are used most, `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate`, both are of type `timestamp` and `roomId` which is a foreign key to the `Rooms` table.

Now Rooms table has PK,  `name` column and `roomNo` column.

This is BookedRooms table:

```
+----+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--+
| PK |          checkInDate       |            checkOutDate |           roomId |  |
+----+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--+
|  1 |     2022-05-26T00:00:00Z   |   2022-05-29T00:00:00Z  |                2 |  |
|  2 |     2022-05-29T00:00:00Z   |   2022-05-30T00:00:00Z  |                3 |  |
+----+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--+
```

This is Rooms table:

```
+----+------------+-------------------+--+
| PK |      name  |            roomNo |  |
+----+------------+-------------------+--+
|  2 |     Deluxe |               102 |  |
|  3 |       King |               103 |  |
+----+------------+-------------------+--+
```

Now, I wanna write a query in which if I put the month number like `4`, it tells me `name` and `roomNo` of `Rooms` which are free for each particular day of the month.

The logic to check if a room is occupied is that, if for example room 102 has a `checkin` date of `03` of month `April` and checkout date of `06` of month `April`, then the query will not include this room in the result set until the checkout date has come, only for that date and onwards would it include room `102` in the result set, again until this room appears in another `checkInDate` column somewhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about this:

```
with
input_month as (
 select 4 as month --> the input months (can be a parameter in a prepared statement)
),
day_geneator as (
select
 date_trunc('year', now())      --> I guess you query for the current year
 + m.month * interval '1 month' --> first day of the month
 + n * interval '1 day'         --> adding 31 days to cover any month
 as day
 from input_month m , generate_series(0,31) n
),
days_of_month as (
select *
from input_month m, day_geneator d
 where d.day <                  --> removes the days in next month
 date_trunc('year', now())  + (m.month + 1) * interval '1 month'
)
select d.day, r.roomNo
from days_of_month d, BookedRooms b join Rooms r on (b.roomId=r.PK)
where not(d.day between b.checkInDate and b.checkOutDate) --> remove non available rooms
order by day, roomno
```

Example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=97c7e1740c31095e2c18d97acd583321